# How to print the contents of (CrystalDecisions) ReportDocument.ExportToStream without creating a file?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

As titled:

> How to print the contents of (CrystalDecisions) ReportDocument.ExportToStream(Type=PDF) without creating a file?

Because we are having issues on access rights of the ASP.NET server printer when executing RptDoc.PrintToPrinter

(Users would log in our system using their Active Directory Account, the printer right is granted to these user accounts instead of to NETWORK SERVICE/the IIS/ASP.NET worker process, our system will impersonate these AD user accounts to do the printing)

(We also do not prefer caching the generated crystal report as a PDF file and do the print)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the [ExportToHttpResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225961%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method

```
crReport.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, false, "Exported Report");
```

The parameters being:

- **formatType** - the format type to export the report
- **response** - the response object of the page
- **asAttachment** - whether the report will be exported as an attachment
- **attachmentName** - the name of the exported report

Comment: sorry, I mean printing the contents to printer

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
ReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(1, True, 0, 0)

PrintToPrinter(nCopies As Integer, collated As Boolean, startPageN As Integer, endPageN As Integer)
```